# How to make Ubuntu 22 accept old Putty connections?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd, putty

I have upgraded from 20 to 22 and now unable to login to it with putty, saying

> Couldn't agree a host key algorithm...

[image]

I would like to make server backwards compatible, not to upgrade putty. How to do this?

Comment: Answered on the sibling site: https://askubuntu.com/a/1409528/911386